# Razor Pages POST Multiple Forms w/ Model Binding

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I have multiple forms on a single razor page that I want to be POSTed after one button is clicked. I tried using a javascript function that would .submit() both forms (put in the onclick= of the button), but only one form's values were actually passed to the OnPost() method serverside. Here's the relevant code from the .cshtml and the .cs files:

StudentMain.cshtml

```
<!--first form-->
<form class="login100-form" method="post">
    <span class="login100-form-title" style="padding-bottom: 38px">
          Student Information
    </span>
    <div class="wrap-input100">
        <input class="input100 has-val" type="text" name="name" value='@ViewData["name"]' readonly/>
        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Student Name"></span>
    </div>

    ...more divs/inputs as above

</form>

<!--second form-->
<form class="login100-form" method="post">
    <div class="wrap-input100">
        <select class="input100 select" name="eduplan" selectedval='@ViewData["eduplan"]'>
            <option disabled selected value style="display:none"/>
            <option>High School Diploma</option>
            <option>Technical Training</option>
            <option>Associate Degree</option>
            <option>Bachelor's Degree</option>
            <option>Advanced Degree</option>
            <option>Military</option>
            <option>Other</option>
        </select>
        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="Education Plan"></span>
    </div>

    ...more divs/selects as above

    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
        <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
            <button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">
                Save
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

StudentMain.cshtml.cs

```
public class StudentMain : PageModel
{
     public void OnPost(string eduplan, string college, string major, string careerpath, string ethnicity, string gender, string ncaa, string firstgen, string onlineinterest)
     {
          Database.SaveStudentData(eduplan, college, major, careerpath, ethnicity, gender, ncaa, firstgen, onlineinterest);
     }
}
```

So, what's the best way to go about doing this? How can I make sure that the values from both forms are passed to the OnPost() method simultaneously? Do I need to use AJAX in some capacity? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

You can use different methods for different form POSTs by specifying the method's name as the value for the `asp-page-handler` tag helper on each form. More information can be found on this [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6PE4p4gUYQ)

***UPDATE***

For example, you have two `POST` methods in your Model class, namely: `OnPostAdd` and `OnPostSubtract`, the different forms to post to the different methods would look like this:

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Add">
    <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Subtract">
    <button type="submit">Subtract</button>
</form>
```

PS: It doesn't matter whether your method is named `OnPostAdd` or `OnPostAddAsync`, ASP.NET Core still expects your handler name to be `Add` as it automatically resolves prefixes like `OnPost`, `OnGet` etc, and suffixes like `Async`

Comment: Could you please summarize the different methods from the video in your answer?

Comment: @EFrank The video only shows one way of doing this, check the update to my answer for more clarity

Comment: Yes some more cleaner code would be nice like separate HTML and C#. But after reading twice got your point and worked. Thanks.